# PHP echo directory contents (as links) not working

Tags: php

I have a php file called download.php which I link to pdf files in a directory. This allows them to appear as links but open 'save as' instead of trying to open in a web page. Trouble is that I can't get the following code to work. It repeats the directory items, with the download.php appended, but I think my php semantics might be slightly wrong! Anyone got any ideas? Perhaps not enough info here to work out, but worth a try: This is the code that sits on the page presenting the various pdf files (ordered by dateLastModified):

```
<?php 
// *** Folder List Repeater Start 
while ($MeetingMinutes->canRepeat()) { 
?> 
<?php echo '<p><a href=\"http://www.duncton.org/download.php?file=login/uploads2/'.$MeetingMinutes->folderList('name').'</a></p><br />'; ?>

 <?php 
 $MeetingMinutes->MoveNext(); 
} 
$MeetingMinutes->endRepeater(); 
// *** Folder List Repeater End 
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you used enough php open/close tags there? ;-)

Comment: Yer! Soz about that! It was because i was trying to id the culprit driving me nuts! :)

Comment: Yer! Soz about that! It was because i was trying to id the culprit driving me nuts! :)

Comment: Check your actual HTML output instead, the error would have been quite obvious.

Answer (score 4):

You're not closing your anchor tag propertly.  You're missing the closing quote and closing bracket.

Try this

```
<?php 
     // *** Folder List Repeater Start 
     while ($MeetingMinutes->canRepeat()) { 
         printf('<p><a href="http://www.duncton.org/download.php?file=login/uploads2/%s">%s</a></p><br />', 
            $MeetingMinutes->folderList('name'), $MeetingMinutes->folderList('name'));

        $MeetingMinutes->MoveNext(); 
     } 

    $MeetingMinutes->endRepeater(); 
    // *** Folder List Repeater End 
?>
```

(edited to remove escape from double quotes)

Comment: Right idea, still the wrong syntax (you're escaping quotes incorrectly, for no reason), and you have no text to actually click. Double-check your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I tried editing it immediatly but I'm getting an error.

Comment: Yeah I got an error when posting the comment, maybe a hiccup on the server. Got another error posting this one.

Comment: Yeah, I tried editing it immediatly but I'm getting an error.

Comment: Thanks Mickey. Sorted that one. Cheers. Still not working, so must be more to this. I'll take it away and hit it with a hammer tomorrow:)

Comment: Finally, it let me edit it to fix it.  I cleaned it up a bit form what you have as well, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks Mickey (and everyone!). That's great neat code. While try it out a.s.a.p. Cheers Martin

Answer (score 3):

You never close your quote for the `href` attribute, and the opening `a` tag.  In addition, you don't have any text for the link, so even if the HTML was correct (which it isn't without the closing quote) it wouldn't actually show up.
Finally - remove the `\`, from `\"` it's not necessary in that context.